# Codeigniter doesn't echo session except in var dump

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I have a very simple codeigniter login function where it sets 3 sessions arrays which two comes from my database. I have been able to echo only one in my view but rest come as objects. I do understand this may be a duplicate but I really need to understand what is happening in this case.

My view

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $my_user->user_id; ?>">
```

Model

public function check_login($email,$password)
        {

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }

    }

    public function get_user_id($email, $password)
    {

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();


    }


    public function get_user_name($email, $password)
    {

    $this->db->select('first_name');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();

    }
```

Controller

```
public function verify_login()

{

    if(isset($_POST['login']))

    {

        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $data['form_red'] = "form-components-red.css";
            $this->load->view('front/header',  $data);
            $this->load->view('front/signin');
            $this->load->view('front/footer');
        }


        else 
        {

            $password = md5($password);
            $this->load->model('users_model');
            $check_login = $this->users_model->check_login($email,$password);
            if ($check_login == TRUE)

            {
                $get_user_id = $this->users_model->get_user_id($email, $password);
                $get_user_name = $this->users_model->get_user_name($email, $password);
                $session_array = array
                (

                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'user_id' => $get_user_id,
                'name' => $get_user_name,


                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_array);
                redirect ('/users/profile_menu');

            }

            else
            {
                $data['error_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Login failed, please enter correct email or password</div>';
                $data['form_red'] = "form-components-red.css";
                $this->load->view('front/header',  $data);
                $this->load->view('front/signin', $data);
                $this->load->view('front/footer');

            }   



        }

    }

    else 
    {

    $data['form_red'] = "form-components-red.css";
    $this->load->view('front/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('front/signin');
    $this->load->view('front/footer');

    }


}



public function update_profile()

{
    // $data['user_data'] = $this->session->all_userdata();

    $data['my_user'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $this->load->view('front/header-menu');
    $this->load->view('front/update_profile',$data);
    $this->load->view('front/footer');
}
```

So as you can see, this is how I get one array item from post and 2 others from database

My var dump looks like this

```
array(3) { ["email"]=> string(22) "me@aol.com" ["user_id"]=> object(stdClass)#15 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } ["name"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (1) { ["first_name"]=> string(7) "Jacki" } }
```

so I can use echo my email using this format

```
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $my_user->email; ?>">
```

but when it comes to other two I have this in my array object(stdClass) which I don't understand how to overcome,

Can you  please advice?

Thank you

Comment: You can chain the object as something $my_user->user_id->id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your model:

```
return $this->db->get()->row()->id;
```

and

```
return $this->db->get()->row()->first_name;
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend mate, worked fine, thank you so much